# Advanced Custom Fields in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some courses on Internet and now I am building a Wordpress theme to continue learning from the experience.

The thing is that I am learning how to install a jquery slider plugin and I see that it's necessary to install advanced custom fields plugin and the repeater plugin that is only available in his pro version ($25) and that's not cool...

Now I would like to know if there is some free good plugin with the same functions of advanced custom fields?

I am just starting my experiments with wordpress to learn everything that I need to start building sites, so I don't have the enough experience to know if it worth to pay the $25 for the advanced custom fields plugin or not.

Do you have some suggestion? It will be something useful in the future? Are there other plugins that you recommends to download even if I have to pay for them?

Comment: You could just add a javascript slider yourself and e.g. use ACF without the repeater field plugin. The only drawback I can think of is that you have to make your fields manually, but in most cases that is a really small task.

I'd just make several image fields and then loop through them and during each iteration append the elements relevant to the chosen slider.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. So I can create for example 10 fields called image1, image2, and like this? The thing is that if I create 10 fields called all of them images it will not work.

Comment: To be honest: It is worth it if you will build wordpress websites on a regular basis.

Comment: ACF is a worthy plugin. Repeater, surely you can buy. meck373 have given exact reply (y).

But as a starter I don't think you need repeater itself. It is for some complex scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's so little context around what you're using the slider for and how much the site admins would need to update slides, etc., but I have two comments:

1. Do you need to use that specific slider? You could rig something up with custom post types, hide the editor and metaboxes, leave only a field for an image upload and whatever meta you like, and have the admin user just add a new post for each slide. Generate those posts in the PHP and have the jQuery slider take it from there. If you're just learning code, that might be more of a challenge, though. I just tend to resist paying for things when there are reasonable alternatives out there.
2. ACF is a worthwhile plugin. If the general context-free question is "Is ACF worth the $25?", the answer is 100% 'yes.' I use it virtually every day and often wonder how I'd make use without it. In your case, if you have other potential use for the project you're on, then yes, I'd say it's worth it. But still, in the simple context of a jQuery slider, I'm hesitant to purchase it just for that.